# Kotlin: How can I get actual generic type T in OneClass<T> in the runtime

Tags: java, generics, types, jvm, kotlin

Friends!
I am a green hand on Kotlin, now here is a problem.
Now I want to get the generic type T in OneClass, here are some peripheral code.

```
// IDatabase.kt
package com.ra
abstract class IDatabase<T> { }
```

```
// Database1.kt
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.javaType
open class Database1<T>: IDatabase<T>() {
    val tClass = this::class.supertypes[0].arguments[0].type!!.javaType as Class<T>
}
```

```
// Database2.kt
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.javaType
open class Database2<T>: IDatabase<T>() {
    val tClass = this::class.supertypes[0].arguments[0].type!!.javaType as Class<T>
    // just wrap a `object` to confort the user
    companion object {
        fun <T> getInstance(): Database2<T> {
            return object: Database2<T>() {}
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the main function follow, where I tested three ways trying to get generic type T, and the results are in the comment under the code each.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val database1 = Database1<String>()
    println(database1.tClass.canonicalName)
    /**
     * Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
     * sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
     * at com.ra.Database1.<init>(Database1.kt:6)
     * at com.ra.MainKt.main(Main.kt:4)
     */

    val database2 = object: Database1<String>() {}
    print(database2.tClass.canonicalName)
    /**
     * java.lang.String
     */

    val database3 = Database2.getInstance<String>()
    println(database3.tClass.canonicalName)
    /**
     * Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
     * sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
     * at com.ra.Database2.<init>(Database2.kt:6)
     * at com.ra.Database2$Companion$getInstance$1.<init>(Database2.kt:10)
     * at com.ra.Database2$Companion.getInstance(Database2.kt:10)
     * at com.ra.MainKt.main(Main.kt:19)
     */
}
```

As you can see there is only one success way -- way 2. But it's not pretty at all. As I want to wrap it in a static function(as way 3 does), it failed again.

So here are my questions:

1. Why the error `ClassCastException` happen?
2. Is there are more pretty ways to solve the problem? If like C#'s solution that will be great.
3. I know the reason of the problem is that JVM erasure the generic type during the compiling time, so I wonder (just in curiosity) when can this change? Or maybe Kotlin or other JVM language may record the generic type information? If has any PLEASE tell me. I've had enough to the type erasure...

Comment: The JVM reduces the type information from `List<String>` to `List` and there is no way for Kotlin around this restriction. Simple answer: Generic type parameters (unless `reified`) are **only available at compile time**

Comment: So what's your way facing the situation like above? Except the @Yuri 's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can work with a reified inline function

```
package com.ba

import kotlin.reflect.KClass

abstract class IDatabase<T> { }

open class Database2<T: Any>(val tClass: KClass<T>) : IDatabase<T>() {
  // just wrap a `object` to confort the user
  companion object {
    inline fun <reified T: Any> getInstance(): Database2<T> = Database2(T::class)
  }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val databaseString = Database2.getInstance<String>()
  println(databaseString.tClass)

  val databaseInt = Database2.getInstance<Int>()
  println(databaseInt.tClass)
}
```

Outputs

```
class kotlin.String
class kotlin.Int
```

Comment: Pretty cool, I LOVE it! But it is likely that you put the class info into the construction function rather than get the T info during the run-time? What if I have a `t: T` in the constructor, then the reified type will unusable?

Comment: If you have an instance of T you can always get the java class of the instance

Comment: I'm not sure if you can have a reified constructor because it relies on inlining the function, in my example you get many copies of the getInstance function.

You can pass in a T in the constructor and use that to get the class as @msrd0 points out.